# add class on click for all modal bootstrap jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have named the type in (brackets) to help explain the problem.

I have a theme on wordpress that uses an old version of bootstrap.css(bootstrap.old.css) and bootstrap.js(bootstrap.old.js). I have removed bootstrap.old.css and enqueued the latest version of bootstrap.css(bootstrap.new.css), however there are some styles missing as some classes have changed in (bootstrap.new.css).

The modal trigger does not work because bootstrap.old.js adds a class .in to the modal window, however there are no styles present for ".in" as in bootstrap.new.css now uses ".show" instead of ".in"

This is the usual markup up a bootstrap button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"> Launch demo modal </button>
```

How do I make it so that if 'data-toggle="modal"': it adds the class ".show" and removes the class ".in" if the "data-target" matches the id of the target (#exampleModal)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

with jquery that targets/triggers automatically using the normal bootsrap button markup without having to specify the id(#exampleModal) in the jquery.

Comment: don't do it by data-toggle, write a function for button click, and trigger modal from there

Comment: and when triggered or before change the class by addclass removeclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can trigger modal in javaScript

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="exampleModal_btn"> Launch demo modal </button>
```

now use a click function to trigger modal and add and remove classes

```
$(document).on("click", "#exampleModal_btn", function () {
    $("#exampleModal").modal();
    $("#exampleModal").removeClass("classname").AddCkass("classname2");
}
```